# Proving definition of limits with definition of continuity and visa versa

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

That is: 
Let $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $x_0 \in D$ is a limit point. Prove $f$ is continuous if and only if $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$.

Also, if $x_0$ is not a limit point, prove $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

I really need help with the right to left direction. The other way was pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little bit tricky because $(\Leftarrow)$ is not always true, it requires the topology on $D$ to be first countable.

The proof is done by contraposition: suppose that $f$ is not continuous at $x_0$, then there exists a sequence $x_n$ converges to $x$ and $f(x_n)$ fails to converge to $f(x)$.

$f$ is not continuous at $x_0$, that means there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $f(x_0)$ such that for each open neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$, we have
$$f(U) \not\subset V.$$

Now let $\{U_h\}$ be a countable base for the neighborhood system of $x_0$ such that $U_{h+1}\subset U_h$ for every $h\in\mathbb{N}$. There exists $x_h\in U_h$ such that $f(x_h)\not\in V$; thus we see that $x_h \rightarrow x_0$ but $f(x_h)\not\rightarrow f(x_0)$.

Edit: if $D$ is equipped with the Euclidean topology, you can just take $V$ to be $B(f(x_0),\epsilon)$, $U$ to be $B(x_0,\delta)$ and $U_h$ to be $B(x_0,\frac{1}{h})$.